# Validate string to match a number/float

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I have got into some trouble with regex, for validating that value is a valid number/float.

**Regex value:** `(?<=^| )\d+((\,\d+)|(\.\d+))?(?=$| )`

Examples that are allowed: "51,5", "54", "54.636", "-45.6", "-2",...

Examples that aren't allowed: "djg52§", "-", "51." "56 8", "89-",...

The **problem** is that this regex contains `positive lookbehind` but it isn't currently supported in Mozilla Firefox. **What would be the alternative for this regex, without lookbehind?**

Comment: Just replace the lookbehind with a normal non-capturing group? If that's not enough, can you provide more context for how the regex is used? Lookahead *is* supported in FF

Comment: Actually, your regex does not match negative numbers and it matches `56 8` as separate numbers.

Comment: You might also reduce the 2 groups  to a single one using a character class `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?`

Comment: Try `/(?:^ ?|\D )(-?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)(?!\S| \d)/`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/g5wfBn/1).

Comment: @CertainPerformance maybe it is supported, but that regexp throws error in FF.

Comment: The error comes from the lookbehind, not from the lookahead. Lookahead has no compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:^ ?|\D )(-?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)(?!\S| \d)
```

Or, if your strings are standalone

```
(?:^\s?|\D\s)(-?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)(?!\S|\s\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g5wfBn/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5E%5Cs%3F%7C%5CD%5Cs)(-%3F%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F)(%3F!%5CS%7C%5Cs%5Cd)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:^\s?|\D\s)`  - a non-capturing group matching start of a string with an optional whitespace after or a non-digit char and a whitespace
- `(-?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1: an optional `-`, 1+ digits and an optional sequence of `,` or `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?!\S|\s\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a non-whitespace char or a whitespace followed with a digit.